# Создание односвязного списка с помощью структур

Tags: c++

Нужно пройтись по каждому элементу списка, пока он не закончится.Запуск данного кода вызывает ошибку. В чём проблема?

```
  #include <iostream>
  using namespace std;

  struct Node{
    int data;
    Node* next;
};

    void add(Node* head, int i){

             do{
                 head = head->next;
                 cout<<"444"<<endl;
             }while(head->next == nullptr);


    }
int main() {

    Node head3 = {1, nullptr};
    Node head2 = {1, &head3};
    Node head1 = {1, &head2};
    add(&head1, 6);

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если вы хотите пройтись по каждому элементу списка с выводом на консоль, это будет означать показать все. Так и назовем функцию:

```
void show_all(Node* head, int i){        
    while (head) {
        cout << head->data <<' ';
        head = head->next;
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
void add(Node* head, int i){
         do{
             head = head->next;            // 1
             cout<<"444"<<endl;
         }while(head->next == nullptr);
    }
}
```

Что будет, когда вы дойдете до конца списка (в 1 получите `nullptr` в `head`)? Вы начнете разыменовывать этот `nullptr`, чтоб проверить `head->next == nullptr` в `while` и, понятно, нарветесь на неприятности...

Кстати, зачем у вас вообще цикл в цикле?...

Comment: Да, на счёт двух циклов ошибся.
Тогда как должно выглядеть правильное решение?

Comment: А что вы вообще хотите? Без ТЗ результат - ХЗ :)